# LINQ2SQL: How to tell if an Entityobject has been updated/Modified before posting to database or not?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How to know if an object (pulled from some datacontext) got updated during some process or not? 
is there any build-in method/prop can do this job, or I must define one (prop, e.g.: Updated) and set it to true every time object got modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by querying the [GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) property of the `DataContext` class. Here's an example:

```
object entity;

bool hasChanged = context.GetChangeSet().Updates.Contains(entity);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check property

```
my_object.EntityState
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.entitystate.aspx

Comment: The `EntityObject` class is used by Entity Framework, not by LINQ to SQL.